# How can we define the terms "computable" and "partially computable" for functions like $f:\mathbb N^k \to \mathbb N^m$

Tags: computability, automata, turing-machines

We say a function $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is computable if it is defined for every $x\in \mathbb N$.

We call a function $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ partially computable if the domain of $f$ is not necessarily all of the natural numbers.

Also, We know that for every $k\in \mathbb N$, there exists a bijection from $\mathbb N^k$ to $\mathbb N$.

So, How can we define more general computable and partially computable functions?

To be more precise:

> Assume that you are given a function $g:\mathbb N^k \to \mathbb N^m$ such that $n,m \in \mathbb N$. How can you tell if $g$ is computable? (or partially computable)

**Note: I know that there are many definitions for this. But I want the definition which is based on the domain of $g$.**

Comment: First you should learn the definition for $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$. "Defined for every $n$" is not the definition of "computable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuition is basically the same as functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Let $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ represent an $n$-tuple, then $g: \mathbb{N} ^n \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^m$ can be written:

$g(\vec{x}) = ( \phi_1(\vec{x}), \phi_2(\vec{x}),...,\phi_m(\vec{x}))$

where the $\phi_i$ represent some algorithm with $\phi_i(\vec{x}) \downarrow$ and $\phi_i(\vec{x}) \uparrow$ meaning the algorithm halts or doesnt halt respectively.  Then:

$g$ is computable (any by implication  partially computable  )$ \Longleftrightarrow \forall \vec{x} \in \mathbb{N}^n: \phi_1(\vec{x})\downarrow, \phi_2(\vec{x})\downarrow,...,\phi_m(\vec{x})\downarrow$

and

$g$ is partially computable and not total$\Longleftrightarrow \exists \vec{x} \in \mathbb{N}^n \exists i \in \{1,2,...,m\}: \phi_i(\vec{x}) \uparrow$

Comment: if i wrote, g is partially computably and not computable iff...

Comment: okay thanks, i changed it.  does that work?

Comment: Also there is an issue in my last comment (I made a mistake). I am deleting it and re-writing correctly in the next comment (I hope it isn't a problem).

Comment: Whenever a function g is "computable" then it is also "partial computable". If one wants to say that a function g is partial computable but not computable ..... you would say something like g is "partial computable but not total".

Comment: In the first condition you wrote I think it should be enough to write "g is computable". In the second condition you write "g is partial computable and not computable". The idea seems about right but it is probably a little better to re-phrase it as "g is partial computable but not total".